# Hiding table columns with jQuery based on column header

Tags: jquery, html-table

I've looked at a couple of similar questions here but I still can's seem to get it to work.  I'm trying to hide specific columns in a table that is being automatically generated on the page. I've managed to hide column header and the corresponding cells in the first row but I'm not sure how to make it work for the rest of the rows. What am I missing?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table.lc_Table:eq(0) tr:eq(0) th").each(function(ind,ele) {
        if( $.trim($(this).text()).match(/(Available|Order Limit)/gi) )
        {
          $("table.lc_Table:eq(0) tr th:eq("+ind+"), table.lc_Table:eq(0) tr td:eq("+ind+")").hide();
        }
    });
});

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" class="lc_Table">
<tr>
    <th class="lc_Heading">
        <p class="PaddedListHeadingsC">Ticket Class</p>
    </th>
    <th class="lc_Heading">
        <p class="PaddedListHeadingsC">Available</p>
    </th>
    <th class="lc_Heading">
        <p class="PaddedListHeadingsC">Order Limit</p>
    </th>
    <th class="lc_Heading">
        <p class="PaddedListHeadingsC">Price</p>
    </th>
</tr>
<tr class="lc_Row0">
    <td class="lc_Cell">
        <p>Attendee1</p>
    </td>
    <td align="right" class="lc_Cell">
        <p>50</p>
    </td>
    <td align="right" class="lc_Cell">
        <p>No Limit</p>
    </td>
    <td align="right" class="lc_Cell">
        <p>$0.00</p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="lc_Row1">
    <td class="lc_Cell">
        <p>Attendee2</p>
    </td>
    <td align="right" class="lc_Cell">
        <p>50</p>
    </td>
    <td align="right" class="lc_Cell">
        <p>No Limit</p>
    </td>
    <td align="right" class="lc_Cell">
        <p>$0.00</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455699/show-hide-table-column-with-colspan-using-jquery for answer with colspan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:eq` is evaluating to only one element. Instead use `:nth-child` which counts relative to an elements parent.

Comment: This worked like a charm thanks... this is what I ended up with.
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table.lc_Table:eq(0) tr:eq(0) th").each(function(ind,ele) {
        if( $.trim($(this).text()).match(/(Available|Order Limit)/gi) )
        {
          $("table.lc_Table:eq(0) tr th:nth-child("+(ind+1)+"), table.lc_Table:eq(0) tr td:nth-child("+(ind+1)+")").hide();
        }
    });
});

Answer (score 3):

Should work

```
$('tr').each(function(){
    $(this).find('td').eq(0).hide();
})
```

For both TH & TD can use

```
$('tr').each(function(){
    $('tr').children().eq(0).hide();
})
```